# Postgres Poor query performance on big table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a transaction table that partitioned by day. On a large environment a one day partition takes 5Gb disk space and ~ 5,000,000 rows.

The following query for 24 time frame took more than 5 minutes, and it is using indexes.

What can be done to improve this?

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM transactions
WHERE end_time > 1488970800000
  AND end_time <= 1489057200000
  AND synthetic_application_id = 1
ORDER BY insertion_time DESC
LIMIT 2000;
```

- I have removed the explanation of partitions that doesn't contain this timeframe as it spend almost no time there.

---

```
Limit  (cost=257809.85..257814.85 rows=2000 width=485) (actual time=323745.024..323758.412 rows=2000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=257809.85..257818.83 rows=3592 width=485) (actual time=323745.008..323749.762 rows=2000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: transactions.insertion_time
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1628kB
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..257597.73 rows=3592 width=485) (actual time=879.457..323670.299 rows=4608 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on transactions  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=2646) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((end_time > 1488970800000::bigint) AND (end_time <= 1489057200000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))

              ->  Index Scan using transactions_p2017_end_time_applicati_idx13 on transactions_p2017_03_08  (cost=0.56..123142.03 rows=1698 width=470) (actual time=879.085..167714.455 rows=2112 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((end_time > 1488970800000::bigint) AND (end_time <= 1489057200000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))
              ->  Index Scan using transactions_p2017_end_time_applicati_idx14 on transactions_p2017_03_09  (cost=0.56..134271.47 rows=1871 width=490) (actual time=395.117..155920.754 rows=2496 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((end_time > 1488970800000::bigint) AND (end_time <= 1489057200000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))

Planning time: 198.866 ms
Execution time: 323765.693 ms
```

Adding another query with explain (analyze, buffers, timing),
It might that some of the data was already loaded in the cache, so the numbers are better. (As i understand there is no way to clear the cache on windows)

```
"Limit  (cost=227818.94..227823.94 rows=2000 width=474) (actual time=139343.951..139356.216 rows=2000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=795 read=40933 written=246"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=227818.94..227830.39 rows=4579 width=474) (actual   time=139343.943..139348.214 rows=2000 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: transactions.insertion_time"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1628kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=795 read=40933 written=246"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..227544.98 rows=4579 width=474) (actual time=733.521..139240.611 rows=4608 loops=1)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=795 read=40933 written=246"
"              ->  Seq Scan on transactions  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=2646) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((end_time > 1488891600000::bigint) AND (end_time <= 1488978000000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))"
"           
"              ->  Index Scan using transactions_p2017_end_time_applicati_idx12 on transactions_p2017_03_07  (cost=0.56..101500.07 rows=2134 width=471) (actual time=733.351..120950.487 rows=1728 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((end_time > 1488891600000::bigint) AND  (end_time <= 1488978000000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=263 read=19902 written=123"
"              ->  Index Scan using  transactions_p2017_end_time_applicati_idx13 on transactions_p2017_03_08  (cost=0.56..125860.68 rows=2422 width=470) (actual time=114.143..18262.152 rows=2880 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((end_time > 1488891600000::bigint) AND (end_time <= 1488978000000::bigint) AND (application_id = 1))"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=498 read=21011 written=123"
"             
"Planning time: 23.858 ms"
"Execution time: 139362.264 ms"
```

Comment: The index scans take all the time, which is surprising given that the index matches the condition exactly. Can you show the index definition? Could it be that the indexes are terminally bloated and need a `REINDEX`?

Comment: `Planning time: 198.866 ms` looks kind of large, too. Maybe the catalogs are also bloated?

Comment: The index definitions is:

 CREATE INDEX transactions_end_time_app_id_ep_id_group_id_index
  ON collector.transactions
  USING btree
  (end_time DESC, application_id, execution_plan_id, agent_group_id);

Comment: I have checked the index size it was 350~400mb to partition, after reindex it took 250mb. Did not saw a big performance improvement.

Also We don't update the rows in this table, it is only insert and truncate partition on retention, so what may cause the indexes to bloat?

Comment: Can you show the output of `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)`? Which Postgres version is that? How many partitions does the table have?

Comment: added, currently the table have 21 partitions

Comment: Please show the results of `VACUUM (VERBOSE)` like @christravers asks in his answer.

Comment: Reading 21011 blocks in 125 seconds is **extremely** slow. 21011 blocks is roughly 170 MB - that shouldn't take two minutes. Is the storage attached through a network?

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `(synthetic_application_id, end_time)` and see if that improves the index scan time.

You seem to have really slow storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a checklist:

1. `vacuum analyze verbose` on all tables involved.  Note the number of rows it says are unremovable. Also see if the performance improves.
2. `explain analyze verbose` to look for more information than we are able to see so far.
3. Try both index orders (the one you have and the one Laurenz suggests above) and see which is used.

I also want to add a note explaining Laurentz's answer and why that may solve your problem.

If your index is on end_time, application_id, then it will check every end_time within the range for application_ids, and chances are you will have a lot of misses.  On the other hand, if you can check the application_id first, then maybe you can avoid checking a lot of end_time records.  So this may solve your problem.  (If you find this helpful you should upvote or accept his answer.)

However note that you need, to create the index on each partition.

Answer (score -1):

Check your work_mem settings for Postgres. If it can't load the whole index into memory, you can get disk thrashing that will slow things down a lot.

Comment: What keeps the index in RAM is a sufficiently high `shared_buffers` setting (or a big file system cache). `work_mem` has no impact here. If it were a bitmap index scan, a big enough `work_mem` would avoid lossy index scans and speed up processing, but here we have a regular index scan. So I think your answer doesn't point in the right direction.